# Javascript - get link href

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

```
function overlay(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    var href = event.target.href;
}
```

But when I use it with HTML like this:

```
    <a href="https://www.somesite.com/" title="Example link" onclick="overlay(event);">Example text</a>
    <!-- ... -->
    <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = href;">Go!</a>
```

So I want to ask how to get the href of the first link and send it to `onclick` event of the second one?

Comment: you'd need to define var href globally (outside the overlay function). Other (maybe better) possibility is to directly set href of second <a> in your overlay function.

Comment: Do you really need 2 links or 1 link would be ok ?

Comment: The second one is in a dialog box that opens once the first one is clicked. I just need to copy the value of the second because I have multiple links that open the sam box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an id on the first anchor element

```
<a id="TargetAnchor" href="https://www.somesite.com/" title="Example link" onclick="overlay(event);">Example text</a>
```

then target it in the click handler of the second

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = document.getElementById('TargetAnchor').href;">Go!</a>
```

Comment: Yeah this worked! Thank you! I'm still learnig JS and I've been hitting my head against the wall all day long because of this! Gonna wait 5 mins to accept your answer...